# Строчные и прописные в цитатах

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Здесь даны две цитаты, представляющие собой отдельные предложения или их части, которые включены в исходное предложение на правах его компонентов. Нужна ли здесь строчная буква в слове "арматурщики"? Или лучше эти цитаты разделить точкой?

Мониторинг форумов, социальных сетей и отраслевых журналов показывает, что в начале 2000–2010-х слово преимущественно писалось в кавычках, т. е. специалисты осознавали его «инородность», необычность: «Российские «арматурщики» собрали форум»; «Арматурщики» взялись за инновации».

Answer (score 2):

Не надо там точки с запятой, обычная запятая. Цитаты выступают как два однородных члена предложения, причем списком с обобщающим словом. Все показания для обычной запятой.

А вот что касается собственно вопроса... Да, Sibylla права, кавычек многовато, но обычно в таких случаях их количество уменьшают по-другому, убирают не внешние, а внутренние - заменой на курсив и т. д. Здесь так не получится - по смыслу. Но и делать из цитаты прямую речь здесь вообще-то тоже нежелательно, путает сильно.

Остается - кавычки разной формы. Я предпочитаю так:

> Мониторинг форумов, социальных сетей и отраслевых журналов
>       показывает, что в начале 2000–2010-х слово преимущественно писалось
>       в кавычках, т. е. специалисты осознавали его «инородность»,
>       необычность: *«Российские "арматурщики" собрали форум»*,
>       *«"Арматурщики" взялись за инновации*».

Хотя слышал и обратную рекомендацию: елочки внутренние, лапочки - внешние. Думаю, что можно выбирать, только следите за последовательностью выбора по всему тексту.

Курсив здесь только как *дополнительное* средство выделения, чисто зрительное.

Заглавную букву менять на строчную причин не вижу, это же законченное предложение, от начала и до конца.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, лучше убрать дословное цитирование, а то слишком много кавычек:

Мониторинг форумов, социальных сетей и отраслевых журналов показывает, что в начале 2000–2010-х слово преимущественно писалось в кавычках, т. е. специалисты осознавали его «инородность», необычность: российские «арматурщики» собрали форум; «арматурщики» взялись за инновации.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется правильней...

Comment: Но все же, а к чему тогда отнести, то, что после двоеточия? Ведь тут же именно говорится о социальных сетях и журналах, т. е. упоминается то, что было написано там...

Comment: Дословно цитирование в этом случае непринципиально, так как мы просто приводим образцы использования слова "арматурщики", заключенного в кавычки. Двоеточие обозначает бессоюзную связь со значение пояснения (можно прямо в текст вставить вводное слово "например"). И по сравнению с исходным текстом (с прямой речь) ничего не изменилось, там вводное слово тоже бы не помешало, так как прямая речь не следует сразу после авторских слов (к примеру, "в журналах и СМИ писалось следующее").